# changing sql table design with foreign keys to model classes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].tbl_emp (
    emp_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    emp_NAME nvarchar(max),
    emp_CONTACT nvarchar(10)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].tbl_allowance (
    allowance_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    allowance_NAME nvarchar(max)
);

CREATE TABLE [dbo].tbl_emp_allowance (
    emp_allowance_id INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY (1, 1),
    emp_id nvarchar INT,
    allowance_id INT 
);
```

These above  sample tables are from our `web form` project. Now we are converting this project to `asp.net mvc 4` applicataion.

I have to change these tables to `code first method`. The challenging part is that I have to create a single page to insert data for `employee [emp_NAME, emp_CONTACT]` and there should also be a drop down to select allowance_NAME for each employee record.
There will be another page for inserting `allowance` info.

I have created the classes for the two tables.

```
[Table("tbl_emp")]
    public class EmpModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int emp_id { get; set; }
        public string emp_NAME { get; set; }
        public string emp_CONTACT { get; set; }
    }
    
[Table("tbl_allowance")]
    public class AllowanceModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int allowance_id { get; set; }
        public string allowance_NAME { get; set; }
    }
```

But I am having problem with the third table. What is the correct way of doing such things in ASP.NET MVC app?

And then how to create the insert page in such a way that, data should be insert to `tbl_emp` and `tbl_emp_allowance`.

Comment: What version of EF are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To bind tables with code first approach simply use this:

```
[Table("tbl_emp")]
    public class EmpModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int emp_id { get; set; }
        public string emp_NAME { get; set; }
        public string emp_CONTACT { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ThirdModel> ThirdModel {get;set;}
    }
[Table("tbl_allowance")]
    public class AllowanceModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int allowance_id { get; set; }
        public string allowance_NAME { get; set; }
        public virtual List<ThirdModel> ThirdModel {get;set;}
    }
[Table("third_table")]
    public class ThirdModel
    {
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Employee")]
        public int EmployeeID{ get; set; }
        public virtual EmpModel Employee { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("Allowence")]
        public int AllowenceID{ get; set; }
        public virtual AllowenceModel Allowence { get; set; }



    }
```

Now our third model contains EmpModel and AllowenceModel. You can access these two models from your third model.

To have a one to many relationship simply use

```
public virtual List<Model1> Model1 {get;set;} // many side

[ForeignKey("Model1")]
public int Model1ID{ get; set; }
public virtual Model1 Model1{ get; set; }// one side
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But if I create views using EF for the `ThirdModel`, will it not create drop down for `EmpModel`? I need to create single page to insert data for `EmpModel` and drop down only for selecting allowance. Please clarify on this.

Comment: DropdownLists are totally different. You can make a viewmodel and put your models in it and send that viewmodel to view to use it as a SelectList<yourmodel>. Many solutions here.